# Problema con mi acumulador en mi codigo Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Tengo un problema con un mini carrito de compras que quiero armar. Cree un array con los productos y sus detalles. Cada producto tiene un botón que al apretarlo lo agrega al carrito de compras. 
En el carrito de compras solo tengo que mostrar la cantidad de productos que llevo comprado y la sumatoria total a pagar. El problema es que no se como hacer para ir sumando los precios a medida que voy apretando el boton de Agregar en los diferentes productos.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="res/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/estilos.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Mi carrito </h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section>
        <h2>Productos</h2>
        <div id="productos">
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script src="parcial_3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var d = document;
var c = console.log;

var productos = d.getElementById("productos");

c(productos);
var prod = [
    {
        Nombre: "Velador Americano",
        Precio: 300,
        Imagen: "items/velador_1.jpg",
        Descripción: "Velador estilo Americano"

    },
    {
        Nombre: "Velador Circular",
        Precio: 350,
        Imagen: "items/velador_2.jpg",
        Descripción: "Velador estilo Circular"

    },
    {
        Nombre: "Velador de Cobre",
        Precio: 250,
        Imagen: "items/velador_3.jpg",
        Descripción: "Velador estilo de Cobre"

    },
    {
        Nombre: "Velador de Cristal",
        Precio: 400,
        Imagen: "items/velador_4.jpg",
        Descripción: "Velador estilo Cristal"

    }

]
c(prod, prod[0].Precio);
var contador = 0;
var acumulador = 0;
c(contador);
for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
    var div = d.createElement("div");
    productos.appendChild(div);
    var img = d.createElement("img");
    div.appendChild(img);
    img.src = prod[i].Imagen;
    img.alt = prod[i].Nombre;
    var div2 = d.createElement("div");
    var h3 = d.createElement("h3")
    h3.innerHTML = prod[i].Nombre;
    div.appendChild(div2);
    div2.appendChild(h3);
    c(div2);
    var p = d.createElement("p");
    var span = d.createElement("span");
    p.innerHTML = "Precio: ";
    div2.appendChild(p);
    span.innerHTML = "$ " + prod[i].Precio;
    var prec = prod[i].Precio;
    c(prec);
    p.appendChild(span);
    var button = d.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Agregar";
    div2.appendChild(button);
    button.onclick = Boton
}
function Boton() {

    contador++;
   
        
    p3.innerHTML = "Total a pagar $ " + acumulador;
    p2.innerHTML = "Items agregados " + " " + contador;
    c(contador);
}

c(contador);
var header = d.querySelector("header");
var div3 = d.createElement("div");
header.appendChild(div3);
var p2 = d.createElement("p");
div3.appendChild(p2);
p2.innerHTML = "Items agregados 0 ";
var p3 = d.createElement("p");
div3.appendChild(p3);
p3.innerHTML = "Total a pagar $0";
var but2 = d.createElement("button")
but2.innerHTML = "Agregar";
div3.appendChild(but2);
```

Comment: Podrías compartir tu HTML?

Comment: Ahí agregue el HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es asociar cada botón con el índice del array de productos, así cuando haces clic en él puedes obtener fácilmente el precio.

Cuando creas el botón:

```
var button = d.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Agregar";
button.dataset.indice = i; // aquí le agregas el dato
```

[dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) es una propiedad que te permite leer y escribir atributos personalizados.

Y lo que tendrías que modificar en el evento de clic:

```
function Boton(evento) {
    var button = evento.target;
    var indice = button.dataset.indice;
    acumulador += prod[indice].Precio;

    // ...
}
```

La función tiene un parámetro que te lo envía el navegador, en este objeto hay información sobre cual fue el botón activado.  Así extraes el índice del producto. El ejemplo completo:

```js
var prod = [
    {
        Nombre: "Velador Americano",
        Precio: 300,
        Imagen: "items/velador_1.jpg",
        Descripción: "Velador estilo Americano"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Velador Circular",
        Precio: 350,
        Imagen: "items/velador_2.jpg",
        Descripción: "Velador estilo Circular"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Velador de Cobre",
        Precio: 250,
        Imagen: "items/velador_3.jpg",
        Descripción: "Velador estilo de Cobre"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Velador de Cristal",
        Precio: 400,
        Imagen: "items/velador_4.jpg",
        Descripción: "Velador estilo Cristal"
    }
];

var d = document;
var c = console.log;

var productos = d.getElementById("productos");

var contador = 0;
var acumulador = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
    var div = d.createElement("div");
    productos.appendChild(div);
    var img = d.createElement("img");
    div.appendChild(img);
    img.src = prod[i].Imagen;
    img.alt = prod[i].Nombre;
    var div2 = d.createElement("div");
    var h3 = d.createElement("h3")
    h3.innerHTML = prod[i].Nombre;
    div.appendChild(div2);
    div2.appendChild(h3);
    var p = d.createElement("p");
    var span = d.createElement("span");
    p.innerHTML = "Precio: ";
    div2.appendChild(p);
    span.innerHTML = "$ " + prod[i].Precio;
    var prec = prod[i].Precio;
    p.appendChild(span);
    var button = d.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Agregar";
    button.dataset.indice = i;
    div2.appendChild(button);
    button.onclick = Boton
}

function Boton(evento) {
    var button = evento.target;
    var indice = button.dataset.indice;
    acumulador += prod[indice].Precio;

    contador++;
    p3.innerHTML = "Total a pagar $ " + acumulador;
    p2.innerHTML = "Items agregados " + " " + contador;
}

var header = d.querySelector("header");
var div3 = d.createElement("div");
header.appendChild(div3);
var p2 = d.createElement("p");
div3.appendChild(p2);
p2.innerHTML = "Items agregados 0 ";
var p3 = d.createElement("p");
div3.appendChild(p3);
p3.innerHTML = "Total a pagar $0";
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Mi carrito </h1>
</header>
<main>
  <section>
    <h2>Productos</h2>
    <div id="productos"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, probe tu codigo y me funciono. Soy un estudiante todavia asi que valoro mucho tu respuesta y enseñanza.

Comment: jajaaja iba a publicar algo idéntico a lo tuyo @Diego, me ganaste xD.